# Load local html into a div in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, iframe

I want to load `LOCAL HTML PAGE` into a div in asp.net web form and it's not necessary to use spacial solution.such as `IFRAME`,`JQUERY.LOAD()` and so on.
How do i do it?
NOTE: this HTML page load from DB and upload to web app so i can't use any URL such as `www.foo.com`  or `http://localhost.` 
I,m glad to hear best practice or any idea or solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after some conversation to use which solution, I do it with jquery.load() function.
when upload my HTML page ,call it with below function.

```
 <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#includedContent").load("../HtmlHolder/index.html");
        });

    </script>
```

and put it in this HTML tag:

```
<div id="includedContent" class="reerer" style="width: 450px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid #808080; margin: 0px auto; overflow-y: scroll;"></div>
```

It worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add an `asp:Literal` tag to your form;
2. Load your HTML markup from DB to a local variable
3. Initialize the `Text` property of the `asp:Literal` tag from the local variable

*Example*

Form:

```
<asp:Literal ID="myHtmlContent" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string html = "<div style='color:red'><b>Hello</b></div>";
       // load HTML from DB insead

        myHtmlContent.Text = html;
    }
```